# Certificate Authentication and Authorization with Apache from a Java Application

Tags: java, apache, authentication, ldap, authorization

I have an Apache server that handles authentication and authorization before forwarding requests to a second server.

Users accessing the server from a browser are authenticating with LDAP and the authorization checks to see that  username is present within a defined file.

I also have a Java application that can access the server (at a different endpoint), which currently hardcodes a username and a password into a request URL and leverages Basic Authentication over SSL.

Rather than use Basic Authentication, is it possible to configure Apache to accept a keystore/truststore from the Java application and authenticate/authorize on the certificate's CN and a password? If so, can anyone cite an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Apache to request client certificate authentication and use `+FakeBasicAuth` `SSLOption` in order to preserve compatibility with your current setup.

If the Java application can be restrained to certain URLs then you can *require* certificate authentication, otherwise make it *optional* as you do not want your other clients to have to authenticate with certificates.

There are good examples of this in the [SSL/TLS - How-To](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol) in the Apache documentation.